# How do I get the jupyter notebook displays embed to QT?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pyqt, ipython

I want the display graph by jupyter notebook embed to my pyqt app

[image: compiled by jupyter notebook]

It seems it's using the function by Ipython display
and may need HTML support

so, is there any way that I can embed these displays to qt, or even a pop out window that can control by qt?

I tried the jupyter console, but I think that's not what I want

Comment: where does "compare_models()" come from?

Comment: A machine learning library for jupyter called pycaret